# Unable to connect to wlan0 via wpa_supplicant

Tags: debian, wpa-supplicant, wlan

I am unable to connect to a wireless network in Debian Linux.

I begin by typing the following command:

```
iwconfig
```

This is my output:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

Next I type:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Then I scan for the networks with this command:

```
iwlist scan | more
```

I see the network that I want to connect too so I know that it is at least visible from my computer.

I then type in this command:

```
cat /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

This is my output:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
    ssid="wireless_network_name"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    psk="wireless_network_password"
}
```

In order to change the ssid and key I use this command:

```
wpa_passphrase "My Network Name" "Password" > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I review the contents of the file and see that they have actually changed to the correct ssid and password.

I then type (this is where the error occurs):

```
wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0
```

The output I get is:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioct1[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioct1[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

I tried kill the process in wpa_supplicant and retrying as well as rebooting. I am at a lost of what to do and would love some direction.

**Suggestion 1 (did not work for me)**

Input:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -D nl80211 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0
```

Output:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
```

Input:

```
ifconfig wlan0
```

Output:

```
flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet6 fe80::3ea3:8ff:fec8:5a87 prefixlem 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 3c:a3:08:c8:5a:87 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 4 bytes 380 (380.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 7 bytes 806 (806.6 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

Input:

```
iwconfig wlan0
```

Output:

```
 wlan0         IEEE 802.11abgn EESID:"My Network Name"
                  Mode: Managed Frequency: 2.437 GHz Access Point: AC:86:74:86:D6:CA
                  Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s     Tx-Power=20 dBm
                  Retry short limit:7     RTS thr:off       Fragment thr:off
                  Encryption key:off
                  Power Management:on
                  Link Quality=68/70 Signal level=-42 dBm
                  Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crpyt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
                  Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0  Missed beacon:0
```

**Suggestion 2**

Add `update_config=1` to wpa_supplicant.conf

Input

```
echo 'update_config=1' >> /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Now run wpa_supplicant command with no -B or -D.

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with ac:86:74:92:fc:8a (SSID='My Network Name' freq=2347 MHz)
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=ac:86:74:92:fc:8a reason=2 locally_generated=1
wlan0: Trying to associate with ac:86:74:92:fc:8a (SSID='My Network Name' freq=2347 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with ac:86:74:92:fc:8a
wlan0: WPA: Invalid EAPOL-Key MIC when using TPIK - ignoring TPIK
wlan0: WPA: Could not verify EAPOL-KEY MIC - dropping packet
Authentication with ac:86:74:92:fc:8a timed out.
```

Input

```
dhclient wlan0
```

This input just loads command forever. Until I press CTRL+C. If I try to ping I get `ping: unknown host www.google.com`

Comment: You want a space between the option `-D` and the value `wext` you are passing to it.

Comment: @jasonwryan this did not fix my issue

Comment: @GAD3R the output is literally nothing. Just goes to the next line.

Comment: I am using a uPC and the wifi card is the WL1837MOD is a WiLink™ 8 based Dual-Band industrial module. I typed `lspci -knn` and again no output just went to the next line. Do I need to navigate to a certain directory?

Comment: @GAD3R This may be wrong but I believe my kernel module is 4.1.15-cl-som-imx7-4.1

Comment: @GAD3R I appreciate your help so far. I have posted your suggestion in my initial post. It did not work

Comment: I'm sorry but what am I suppose to do with this file? I am very new to Linux and I appreciate the help that you have given so far but I do not know what I am suppose to do with this file.

Comment: @GAD3R so maybe this is my issue. I do not have a `wpasupplicant` file under doc

Comment: I really appreciate your help but this is still not working. I just do not know what to do anymore. It should not be this hard to connect to a wireless network.

Comment: Does the Access point  use WPA2 enterprise?

Comment: I have tried connecting using a G200 router from OpenMesh and a NETGEAR Nighthawk x10. I am starting to think it is the uPC. I have reached out to the manufacture but they are located in Israel so I will not hear back from them until tomorrow.

Comment: Are you getting any additional (explaination) from the manufacture?

Comment: I have been in and out of contact with them. I ran the command `wpa_supplicant -dd -D wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0` which runs a debug of `wpa_supplicant`. They told me to continue using `D wext` They suggested uninstalling and then reinstalling the kernel. Something that I am not looking forward to attempting. I will attach the debug file to this post. I do not know what I am looking at.

Answer (score 2):

The wireless extensions `wext` have been [deprecated](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/wext-statement) in favor of `nl80211`.

Could you please try the command

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -D nl80211 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0
```

Note that using wpa_supplicant directly in the way you intend to do will only work, when no frontend program (such as networkmanager) using wpa_supplicant is already running.

Comment: `wext` *is* a valid argument, and while it has been deprecated it is still a necessary option for older cards.

Comment: sure agreed, but judging by the output posted by OP I assume this will fix the problem

Comment: The output says "invalid argument"...

Comment: I get the same output as OP on my system using `wext`. However using `nl80211` everything works fine.

Comment: Normally I would have posted my answer as a comment. But I am not yet able to do so on this site.

Comment: @oh.dae.su I substituted `wext` with `nl80211` and did not get any invalid arguments and just received the output `Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant`. However, I do not think that I have actually connected to a wireless network as I pinged google and had 100% of packets loss.

Comment: Do you already have an instance of Networkmanager running by any chance? What does `ifconfig wlan0` and `iwconfig wlan0` say?

Comment: @oh.dae.su I have updated my initial question with your requests

Comment: @GAD3R I have done that and it either says `RTNETLINK answes: file exists` or just goes to the next line without any output. I am still unable to ping anything

Comment: @oh.dae.su so what do you suggest? I really appreciate the help that everyone is giving me. I am really trying to get connected to a wireless network by the end of today.

Comment: you could try this sequence before calling wpa_supplicant (not sure this is the solution, but worth a try): 1)`sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` 2)`sudo ip addr flush dev wlan0` 3)`sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`